# SwiftData: Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have 2 pretty models and want to create some dummy preview data for these but I'm running into error:

**Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'person' between objects in different contexts**

The error happens here:

```
@MainActor
let previewContainer: ModelContainer = {
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(
            for: Person.self, Item.self,
            configurations: ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
        )
        let person = Person.dummy()
        container.mainContext.insert(person)
        for i in 0 ..< 12 {
            let item = Item.dummy(i, person: person) //ERROR!
            container.mainContext.insert(item)
        }
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to create container \(error)")
    }
}()
```

**I'm using Xcode 15 beta 8**. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here are my models for reference:

Item Model

```
@Model
final class Item {
    var note: String
    var person: Person

    init(note: String, person: Person) {
        self.note = note
        self.person = person
    }
    
    static func dummy(_ index: Int, person: Person) -> Item {
        return Item(
            note: "Item number \(index)",
            person: person
        )
    }
}
```

Person Model

```
@Model
final class Person {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(
        deleteRule: .cascade, 
        inverse: \Item.person
    )
    var items: [Item] = []
    
    init(name: String, items: [Item] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = [Item]
    }
    
    static func dummy() -> Person {
        return Person(
            name: "John Doe"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ran into something similar on the latest Beta.

WWDC videos don't mention this explicitly but looking at their data models it seems like all **@Relationship** fields need to be either:

- Optional
- Provide a default value

For example:

```
@Model
final class Trip {
    var destination: String?
    var end_date: Date?
    var name: String?
    var start_date: Date?
  
    @Relationship(.cascade)
    var bucketListItem: [BucketListItem] = [BucketListItem]() //<--
  
    @Relationship(.cascade)
    var livingAccommodation: LivingAccommodation? //<--
}
```

Try setting:

```
var person: Person?
```

In your **Item** model.